# Clickhouse columns structure

Tags: mysql, statistics, database-administration, clickhouse

I store statistics data in MySQL and want to migrate it to the Clickhouse.

For one entity I have multiple statistics types. For examples: `clicks`, `views`, `upvotes`

And now I store it in the table which looks like: `entity_id | datetime | type | value`, where `type` is a constant integer which corresponds to one of statistics types described above.

Is it better to keep the same structure in Clickhouse or to create the next schema: `entity_id | datetime | clicks | views | upvotes`

As I understood, the Clickhouse is column-oriented DB. Does it mean that the Clickhouse has zero-cost altering when we want to add new columns, when it will be necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it better to keep the same structure in Clickhouse or to create the next schema

if `clicks | views | upvotes` are related to same `entity_id`, then it makes sense to create a column for each value. By doing this, you will run one query and get a row containing all the data you need.

On the other hand, if you create table as `entity_id | datetime | type | value`, then you will have flexibility to have more statistic types(maybe `mouse_enter` as a 4th type). In the same time, you will have repeated `entity_id` and `datetime` values which will cost you disk usage and your table will have 3x rows. As you can see, there is a trade-off between each decision. It's up to you to decide which one to choose. If you think that only `clicks | views | upvotes` will be enough then it makes much more sense to use this schema.

> Clickhouse is column-oriented DB. Does it mean that the Clickhouse has zero-cost altering when we want to add new columns, when it will be necessary

Yes, Clickhouse is column-oriented and each column is a separate file(s) on the disk. So there will be little to none overhead if you create a new column. But altering a column will take time if you use table mutations or alter the type, depending on the operation.

Comment: Hm, it means that second case with the `type` field has only cons. Bcoz` ClickHouse has ~ none overhead if I create a new column. So when I want to add a new statistics type, I can do it instantly. Also there is another pros for the first case, if statistics columns has different data types. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @MikhailStroev that is correct and I think you should have a column for each metric. Also, check this answer which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391255/clickhouse-as-time-series-storage/46995670#46995670